# Re-initialize object properties in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, oop

I often have a class with properties that are initialized at instantiation, like

```
class C {
  var x = 10
  var y = v * 2  // v is some variable
}

val c = C()
```

then properties of `c` are changed, and later I need to re-initialize the properties (so that `c.x` is `10` again and `c.y` is `v*2`, where the value of `v` may have changed).

My current approach is to initialize the properties with dummy values (or alternatively use `lateinit` and type annotations), and assign the desired values in an extra function `ini` like

```
class C {
  var x = 0
  var y = 0

  init {
    ini()
  }

  fun ini() {
    x = 10
    y = v * 2
  }
}
```

then I call `c.ini()` to re-initialize.

**Is there a better (more succinct) way that avoids the dummy values?**

Note that in JavaScript I can simply write

```
class C {
    constructor() {
        this.ini()
    }
    ini() {
        this.x = 10
        this.y = v * 2
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by a "better" way? What's not good about this way? Do you not want to create a new instance of `C`?

Comment: I want to avoid the overhead of the dummy values, it's not a big deal, but I thought maybe there's a more succinct solution

Comment: There is no meaningful overhead for that. Don't worry about it.

Comment: I just thought of a more succinct way by abusing property delegates and reflection. That's probably overkill for this situation though. What you are doing is fine.

Comment: @Tenfour04 not in execution performance of course, just bloats the code if I have many such classes with a lot of such properties, but maybe you're right anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing right now is totally fine. I wouldn't change it.

If you want to avoid the placeholder values of `0`, or if the type of the property has no placeholder value that make sense, you can store the initial values in private lambdas:

```
class C {
  private val xInit = { 10 }
  private val yInit = { v * 2 }

  var x = xInit()
  var y = yInit()

  fun reset() {
    x = xInit()
    y = yInit()
  }
}
```

If you *really* want to reduce the boilerplate, I can only think of this rather hacky and slow solution that relies on reflection. This *could* be usable if the instances don't need to be reset that often, and you have lots of these classes with resettable properties, and you just hate writing boilerplate `reset` methods.

```
class Resettable<T>(val supplier: () -> T) {
    var wrapped = supplier()

    operator fun getValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>): T {
        return wrapped
    }

    operator fun setValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>, value: T) {
        wrapped = value
    }

    fun reset() {
        wrapped = supplier()
    }
}

fun <T: Any> T.reset() {
    // look for properties delegated with Resettable
    this::class.memberProperties.mapNotNull {
        it.isAccessible = true
        (it as KProperty1<T, *>).getDelegate(this)
    }.filterIsInstance<Resettable<*>>().forEach {
        it.reset()
    }
}
```

Now you just need to do:

```
var v = 10
class C {
    var x by Resettable { 10 }
    var y by Resettable { v * 2 }
}

fun main() {
    val x = C()
    println(x.y) // 20
    v = 20
    x.reset()
    println(x.y) // 40
    v = 40
    x.reset()
    println(x.y) // 80
}
```

Note that the first `reset` call would load all the kotlin reflection classes, and would take a noticeable amount of time.

Comment: Sweeper, thanks for your extensive answer! Then I think I'll stay with my solution. I've added a comparison with JavaScript, I suppose boilerplate will be necessary in most or all statically typed languages?